# Inserting element into sorted vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I wrote a C++ program with the goal of quickly inserting an element into a sorted vector. It works sometimes but not all of the time and I have not been able to figure out why. When I follow the algorithm with a paper and pencil it works out but something is wrong. Please help?

```
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<int> sortedVec;

int main() {
    // Random seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    // Put in n random elements
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) sortedVec.push_back(rand()%10);

    // Sort the vector
    bool swapped = true;
    int endDecrement = 0;
    while (swapped) {
        swapped = false;
        endDecrement++;
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedVec.size()-endDecrement; i++) {
            if (sortedVec.at(i) > sortedVec.at(i+1)) {
                int swap = sortedVec.at(i);
                sortedVec.at(i) = sortedVec.at(i+1);
                sortedVec.at(i+1) = swap;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<"Sorted random list:"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedVec.size(); i++) cout<<sortedVec.at(i)<<endl;

    int toInsert = rand()%10;
    cout<<"Random element to insert = "<<toInsert<<endl;

    // Insert a random int to the sorted vector
    int minIndex = 0;
    int maxIndex = sortedVec.size()-1;
    while (true) {
        int mid = (maxIndex-minIndex)>>1;
        if (toInsert == sortedVec.at(mid) || maxIndex-minIndex < 2) {
            sortedVec.insert(sortedVec.begin()+mid, toInsert);
            break;
        }
        else if (toInsert < sortedVec.at(mid)) maxIndex = mid;
        else if (toInsert > sortedVec.at(mid)) minIndex = mid;
    }

    cout<<"Random list with inserted element:"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedVec.size(); i++) cout<<sortedVec.at(i)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `std::set` which sorts the elements for you? And event if you want to use vector, you can achieve sorting using `std::sort` and finding the position to insert using `std::equal_range` algorithms instead of writing you own.

Comment: If you're going to do it this way, is there a reason not to use `std::sort` to do your sort and `std::upper_bound` to find your insertion point? (but if you want to insert in order, this really isn't the best way to do it, IMO).

Comment: @Jerry Coffin, This is a dummy program to solve the same problem in a different program. The other program does an A* search and inserts new Nodes into a vector named tree. The problem is that I don't know how to use std::upper_bound with a value from the Node class (I am brand new to C++). The Node class has an int named fVal which is the thing I want to be used to determine the position of an insertion to the vector. If I could get std::upper_bound to check tree.at(whatever position).fVal that'd be great.

Comment: "a vector named tree" should probably be a `std::set` or `std::multiset` depending on your needs - though I agree, if you have other code assuming it's a `vector`, the migration can be painful too.

Comment: @asimes: Yes, you can do that -- `upper_bound` allows you to specify a comparison function/functor. In your case its logic will just be  `return a.fval < b.fval;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it and am pretty sure it works in all cases now:

```
if (toInsert < sortedVec.at(0)) sortedVec.insert(sortedVec.begin(), toInsert);
else if (toInsert > sortedVec.at(sortedVec.size()-1)) sortedVec.push_back(toInsert);
else {  
    int minIndex = 0;
    int maxIndex = sortedVec.size();
    while (true) {
        int mid = (maxIndex+minIndex)>>1;
        if (toInsert == sortedVec.at(mid) || maxIndex-minIndex < 2) {
            sortedVec.insert(sortedVec.begin()+mid+1, toInsert);
            break;
        }
        else if (toInsert < sortedVec.at(mid)) maxIndex = mid;
        else if (toInsert > sortedVec.at(mid)) minIndex = mid;
    }
}
```

@LeGEC and @chac, thank you for looking into the algorithm I posted, it helped a lot. @Jerry Coffin, I did get std::upper_bound to work for this but not for a variable of my Node class, thank you as well though.

Comment: It does not work. Inserting firstly 1 than 0 will result in vector (1,0)

Comment: Here You can find proper implementation of lower bound http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/

Comment: Can you explain further? Do you mean if you start with an empty `vector`, insert 1, then 0? I got an error when I tried that. When I wrote this I had the assumption that the list already had elements in it.

Comment: Yes, that's the case when it doesn't work with empty vector at the begining.

Comment: I guess what I meant is how did you get it to produce a vector with elements V = {1, 0}. When I changed the program to use the code with an empty vector it just throws an error.

Comment: Probably I wrote additional case to add element to empty list.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments pointed out, what you propose is a rather convoluted way to solve a basic problem.

Your question could be made more attractive replacing `time(NULL)` in random generator initialization with a constant that gives the observed behaviour to debug.

Without that, I will place a bid on culprit:

```
int maxIndex = sortedVec.size()-1;
```

I think should be

```
int maxIndex = sortedVec.size();
```

or you never consider the top element.

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work every time. This is a dummy program to solve a trickier problem that is similar. The other problem will always have unknown incoming values to be inserted to a vector full of elements with unknown but sorted values.

Comment: If you intend to use this in production code, I would also strongly suggest using the functions already coded in the STL. There is a second culprit : `maxIndex-minIndex < 2` implies that you do not do the last comparison. It should be `maxIndex == minIndex`.

Comment: @LeGEC, I'm pretty sure that maxIndex will not always equal minIndex for every possible case. I did try making that change but it still does not work. After making chac's change and using maxIndex-minIndex<2 it works about 3/4 of the time which is really frustrating.

Comment: Last and not least, `mid` should be `(maxIndex+minIndex)>>1;` (instead of `(maxIndex-minIndex)>>1;`). I insist : use standard algorithms. `std::upper_bound` has a template version where you supply your comparison function.

Comment: @LeGEC: that's the true bug! And you are obviously totally right when requiring to use STL.

Comment: @chac: The true bug is a combination of the three :) (I'm checking for a fourth...)

Comment: @LeGEC, THANK YOU! I cannot believe I overlooked that. I just assumed I had written + when I was checking it with paper and pencil repeatedly... oy. I did get std::upper_bound to work for vector<int> someVector, but I don't know how to implement it for vector<Node> tree, where I want to sort by tree.at(some position).fVal.

Comment: Turns out it still does not always work for larger vectors. I think I'll just try to get std::upper_bound working.

Comment: do you need help to write the functor for upper_bound? it can be done as free function bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b) { ... } or a struct with a member bool operator() const (const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b) {...}

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, let's assume we have a structure something like:

```
struct data {
    int fval;
    // other stuff we don't care about right now
};
```

And, we'll assume we have a vector of these:

```
std::vector<data> items;
```

If we want to insert a new item into the vector in order, we *don't* really want to do a binary search followed by `std::insert`. This requires an O(log N) search followed by an O(N) insertion. Instead, we can combine the two, so we only need a single O(N) operation to find the right place and do the insertion. Here's a simple version:

```
void insert(std::vector<int> &vec, int new_val) { 
    if (vec.empty()) {
        vec.push_back(new_val);
        return;
    }

    vec.resize(vec.size()+1);
    std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator pos = vec.rbegin();

    for ( ; *(pos+1) > new_val && (pos+1) != vec.rend(); ++pos)
        *pos = *(pos+1);
    *pos = new_val;
}
```

In your case, you want to insert a `data` struct, and compare `(pos+1)->fval > new_val.fval`, but the basic idea is otherwise pretty much the same. In reality, this *should* probably be implemented as a generic algorithm, but I don't have time at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

There are facilities in the Standard library for sorting:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename A, typename C>
class SortedVector {
public:
    SortedVector() {}

    // Initialization
    template <typename It>
    SortedVector(It begin, It end): _data(begin, end) {
        std::sort(_data.begin(), _data.end(), _comparator);

        // if we wanted unicity
        _data.erase(std::unique(_data.begin(), _data.end(), _comparator), _data.end());
    }

    // Addition of element (without checking for unicity)
    void add(T const& element) {
        _data.push_back(element);
        std::inplace_merge(_data.begin(), prev(_data.end()), _data.end(), _comparator);
        // or simply: std::sort(_data.begin(), _data.end(), _comparator);
        // it is surprisingly efficient actually because most sort implementations
        // account for partially sorted range. It is not, however, stable.
    }

    // Addition of element with unicity check
    bool add(T const& element) {
        typename std::vector<T, A>::iterator it =
            std::lower_bound(_data.begin(), _data.end(), element, _comparator);
        if (it != _data.end() and not _comparator(element, *it)) {
            return false;
        }
        size_t const n = it - _data.begin();

        _data.push_back(element);
        std::copy(_data.begin() + n, _data.end() - 1, _data.begin() + n + 1);
        // C++11: std::move
        _data[n] = element;
    }

private:
    std::vector<T, A> _data;
    C _comparator;
};
```

Comment: +1 But I think it would be even nicer to remove the `n`, since `std::copy(it, std::prev(_data.end()), std::next(it)); *it = element;` would do, too, and would be way "`std`-cleaner". And I think you need to include `<iterator>` and `std`-qualify `prev` in the first `add`. Ok, maybe there's no C++11, but `it` is still better than `_data.begin()+n`.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Actually, `it` is invalidated by the `push_back` call (potentially).

Comment: @ChristianRau: I would not call you stupid, it's a kinda poor interface when screwing up is so easy...

Answer (score 0):

*I wrote a C++ program with the goal of quickly inserting an element into a sorted vector*

You shouldnt have done that.  std::vector is not suitable for quick insertion to custom position. 
EDIT: BTW you are doing replacement, not insertion. For that use of vector is ok.

Also your code suffers from not using standard functions. std::sort, also you have std::swap if you really want to manually swap elements.

Also this is unnecessary :

```
int mid = (maxIndex-minIndex)>>1;
```

Compiler can and do easily optimize /2 to >>1;

**EDIT:**

Your code is broken, this will hopefully show you why:
http://ideone.com/pV5oW